# Bootstrap slider remove </a> when it is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a weird problem with bootstrap slider, I've added href in each slide as far as I know it is possible.

I have everything set and It should work, and it works and If I check the source code in Chrome I see that:

```
<div id="gallery" style="width:397px!important">

<div style="width:397px!important" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div style="width:397px!important" class="active item"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.reservon.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/34/slide1.png"/></a> </div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/2"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/2/slide2.png"/> </a> </div>
        <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="www.marca.com"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/10/slide3.png"/> </a> </div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/83"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/83/slide4.png"/> </a> </div>
        <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/20/slide5.png"/> </a> </div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/28"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/28/slide5.png"/> </a> </div>
    </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });

</script>
```

But If I use the Chrome inspector every link doesn't have the `</a>` but the first.

```
    <div id="gallery" style="width:397px!important">

<div style="width:397px!important" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div style="width:397px!important" class="active item"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.reservon.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/34/slide1.png"/> </a></div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/2"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/2/slide2.png"/> </div>
        <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="www.marca.com"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/10/slide3.png"/> </div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/83"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/83/slide4.png"/> </div>
        <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/20/slide5.png"/> </div>
        <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/28"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/28/slide5.png"/> </div>
    </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });

</script>
```

I suppose that as soon as the slider is loaded it removes the other anchor end tags but why?

Any idea??? I cant fix it and only the first link works... :S

Thanks!

Comment: Why your <div> tag is not closed ? its like this `<div style="width:397px!important"  class="item"` instead of `<div style="width:397px!important"  class="item">`.

Comment: u are right, I was very tired and I didn't see... soz

Comment: Glad it worked for you!
Please accept my answer !

Comment: Please use better tags in future. Also, stop using "bootstrap", use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else.

Answer (score 1):

These are coded incorrectly. You are missing carets at the end of the div (.item)

```
 <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" 
 <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/2"> 
 <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/2/slide2.png"/> </div>
```

Should be this:

```
 <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item">
 <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/2"> 
 <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/2/slide2.png"/></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: are u kidding me? ofcourse are missing characters, that is the problem, in my code, as soon as the web page is loaded as I said, if u look the source code with Chrome, the anchor's end tag are in their place but if you inspect the code with Chrome inspector everyone but the first doesn't have the anchor's end tag,that's the problem.

Comment: S0 when another person, Rohil_PHPBeginner, comments you didn't close your div tag in your written code, you say sorry but when I point it out you say u kidding me? WTF? You posted the code supposedly WRITTEN BY YOU in the first block and it lacked an ending div closure, which, if you don't know it, is an issue in setting up any html code. Your pretty rude for someone asking for help, when you actually posted incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing tag in `<div>`.

```
    <div id="gallery" style="width:397px!important">

    <div style="width:397px!important" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div style="width:397px!important" class="active item"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.reservon.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/34/slide1.png"/></a> </div>
            <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/2"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/2/slide2.png"/> </a> </div>
            <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="www.marca.com"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/10/slide3.png"/> </a> </div>
            <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/83"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/83/slide4.png"/> </a> </div>
            <div  style="width:397px!important" class="item" <a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.es"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominios/20/slide5.png"/> </a> </div>
            <div style="width:397px!important"  class="item" <a href="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/eventosPub/dealle/28"> <img src="http://localhost/reservasHosteleria/central/images/dominiosRG/28/slide5.png"/> </a> </div>
        </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Pointed out to him in my answer as well, yet I got a "u kidding me"

Comment: And yet some folks wonder why we wrote [LMVTFY](https://github.com/cvrebert/lmvtfy)...(sigh)